# MSAL - Application can request permission even if it's not configured in 'API Permissions'

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver3, azure-ad-msal

I have created a small .NET Core 3.1 console application using the MSAL library which requests scope `api://55a047a1-a0d1-4b6b-9896-751a848e1e06/testscope2`

Custom API exposes two scopes

- api://55a047a1-a0d1-4b6b-9896-751a848e1e06/testscope1
- api://55a047a1-a0d1-4b6b-9896-751a848e1e06/testscope2

[image]

I have also configured another application named `test-app` in Azure Active Directory which represents my console application.

I have configured only one API permission (`api://55a047a1-a0d1-4b6b-9896-751a848e1e06/testscope1`) for this application. My understanding is with this configuration in place client app will only be able to request for scope `test1` and it won't allow `test-app` to request for `scope2`

Below is screenshot

[image]

This is my code:

```
//<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.13.0" />
namespace console_client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region Azure AD parameters
            var clientId = "dddeefa5-d95c-4931-a53d-2382deee27c3";
            var tenant = "-- MY TENANT ID--";
            var instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
            #endregion

            var client = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                .WithAuthority($"{instance}{tenant}")
                .Build();

            List<string> scopes = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                // I was under impression that this call will throw as exception as
                // this app is requesting 'testscope2' which is not included in API Permissions
                // while configuring test-app in Azure Active Directory (dddeefa5-d95c-4931-a53d-2382deee27c3 )
                // But I was able to retrieve token back with testscope2 in it.
                scopes.Add("api://55a047a1-a0d1-4b6b-9896-751a848e1e06/testscope2");
                var authenticationResult = client.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine($"Interactive Access token is : {authenticationResult.AccessToken}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                System.Console.WriteLine($"******* {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

Am I missing anything? Why am I getting the access token back even if the app doesn't have permission configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR it is a feature.

With the v2 endpoint / MSAL, you can request for scopes that are not defined in your app manifest.
The ones in your app registration are the *static* permissions required by your application.
But your application can also request *dynamic* permissions at login time.
The user/admin would still need to consent to that of course, an app won't get a permission without consent.

Your app seems to be a single-tenant app so this doesn't really make a difference for you.
It is mainly for multi-tenant SaaS applications that can require the minimum needed permissions in the app registration/manifest, and then request more permissions for opt-in features as they are needed.

By the way, if you want to use the permissions defined in your app registration, you can request a special scope: `api://55a047a1-a0d1-4b6b-9896-751a848e1e06/.default` (your app ID URI or client id + "/.default").
This will make AAD look at your app registration to decide which permissions to check consent for.